# WordPress - How can I update user meta data outside of the user's profile? I've provided the code I'm using to display

Tags: php, wordpress

Using user meta data, I am running a function that is hidden in a user’s profile that allows them to have a checklist. I’m using Theme My Login and not including the checklist on the user’s profile page when they edit/view their profile.

I am trying to display the checklist on it’s own page. I can get it to display but can’t seem to get the Submit button to work. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Code example in functions.php:

```
function my_show_extra_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id=" checkbox1 " value="yes" <?php if (esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( "checkbox1", $user->ID )) == "yes") echo "checked"; ?> />
Checkbox 1
</div>
<button type="submit">Save</button>
<?php }
?>
<?php
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'my_save_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'my_save_extra_profile_fields' );

function my_save_extra_profile_fields( $user_id ) {

if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
    return false;

update_usermeta( $user_id, checkbox1, $_POST['checkbox1'] );
}
?>
```

Code example to display the extra profile field on my page template:

```
<?php my_show_extra_profile_fields(); ?>
```

EDIT: Forgot my '', added them back in

Answer (score 0):

You have $_POST[checkbox1]  it should be   $_POST['checkbox1']

Assuming you created the field already, you can use  [wp_update_user](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_user) from the codex.

```
$user_id = wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $user_id, 'checkbox1' => $_POST['checkbox1']  ) );

if ( is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
    // There was an error, probably that user doesn't exist.
} else {
    // Success!
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ricardo Nuñez. Updated my post to include the '', don't know why they didn't show up the first time. I tried adding the code you provided, but can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: How you created the field in the database? Are you able to see the data?

Comment: The data shows up, and is only editable through wp-admin > edit user. I'm trying to somehow tie the submit button in my code to something that will update the field in the database. Something that allows the user to update their own checkbox If I add a form tag around it, it still does nothing.

Comment: edit_user_profile_update only triggers when a user is viewing another user's profile page (not their own). You need to use personal_options_update check http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/edit_user_profile_update

Comment: Tried calling it by wrapping it in a form and using 
    <form onsubmit="<?php my_save_extra_profile_fields( $user_id )?>">  but that didn't work either.